# Writing to framebuffer on C is very slow (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: linux, c, raspberry-pi-os, framebuffer

I want to make a very intensive simulation and need the most power the Raspberry Pi gives me. So I flashed Raspberry Pi OS Lite (without Desktop) onto an Micro SD Card and wrote to the framebuffer in C using the example found here: http://raspberrycompote.blogspot.com/2013/03/low-level-graphics-on-raspberry-pi-part.html
The problem is, that this is VERY slow. I can see the image being updated and scanning from top to bottom and it takes very long (0.2s or so), which means, I can never get 30 or 60 fps.
Is there a better (and faster) way to do this? The X Window Manager of Raspberry Pi OS must also somehow write to the framebuffer to be able to work, so there must be a faster way...
I hope that my problem is clear and understandable and I am looking forward to helpful answers! :)

Comment: *"The X Window Manager of Raspberry Pi OS must also somehow write to the framebuffer to be able to work"* -> No, although it can this is usually only used when there is no other choice because there's no Xorg driver for the hardware (the "linux framebuffer" isn't hardware).

Answer (score 0):

Graphic displays normal rely upon a GPU, and the RPi is no different. There are details [here](https://petewarden.com/2014/08/07/how-to-optimize-raspberry-pi-code-using-its-gpu/) for optimising code using it. I can't say that the RPi GPU will help you out in this case, but it may be worth a look at. There is a compiler to make things easier by Pete Warden [here](https://github.com/mn416/QPULib).

Answer (score 0):

to obtain the frame rates that you want, you need hardware frame buffers (at least two)

then while one frame buffer is being displayed, the other frame buffer is receiving new data.